# mocha full coverage test using json schema

Tags: javascript, api, integration-testing, mocha.js

I have written a test for a get request, but want to get "full coverage" for this test. Basically, I want to use something like JSON Schema to validate that the JSON return matches my expectations.

My code so far is below:

```
var winston = require('winston');
//var chai = require('chai');

var request = require('supertest-as-promised');
var testUtils = require('./utils/test_utils');

var API_ROOT = 'http://localhost:8000/mywebsite';

var agent = request(API_ROOT);

describe('/my-profile/', function(){
  describe('GET', function() {

    var url = '/my-profile/';

    it('should return valid payload', function(done) {

        agent.
            get(url).
            set('Content-Type', 'application/json').
            expect('Content-Type', /json/).
            expect(200).
            // then(testUtils.logResponse).
            then(function(res) {
                done();
            }).catch(function(err) {
                // winston.log(res).then(done);
                done(err);
            });

    });
  });


});
```

How do I go about using json schema for validate. Any sample links? comment? code?

Answer (score 2):

You might try using [Chai json-schema plugin](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-json-schema/). Which let's you make assertions like the following:

`expect(goodApple).to.be.jsonSchema(fruitSchema);
expect(badApple).to.not.be.jsonSchema(fruitSchema)`

See the website for full details.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to use something "like" json schema to validate the returned JSON, well, Chai assertions would suit the task just fine.

Just test for the presence of properties with the property chain, or check that they are of the correct type with the instanceof chain. If you know exactly what the api should return for a given test case, construct a matching object and compare it with the deep chain.